# Generic method with property expression "type arguments cannot be inferred from useage"

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I hope I'm not having a meltdown here - will happily delete this question if I am... but given the following method:

```
IList<T> ConvertSomething<T, TProperty>(IList<T> original, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> valuePropertyExpression, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> namePropertyExpression);
```

..I can call it like this:

```
var data = new List<MyType>(); // would be real data of that type
var output = _factory.ConvertSomething<MyType, object>(data, x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

..but not like this:

```
var output = _factory.ConvertSomething(data, x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

The second version causes the compiler to complain, with the "cannot be inferred from useage" error.

So my questions are:

1. is what I am doing possible when only the method can know about `T`
2. if not, is there another approach (I need to know the two requested `PropertyInfo` objects to do my 'conversion' and don't want the user to have to do it by string).

Comment: What are the types of `.Id` and `.Name`? Is `.Id` a value type that you want boxed into `object`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not exactly related. @ Selman22 has nailed it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen See answer below. The types could be anything to answer your question, but I was trying to use "TProperty" twice, when they could (probably would) be of a different type. So the answer is to have a third generic parameter.

Comment: The types could be anything where neither type is implicitly convertible to the other. If `Id` had compile-time type `object`, and `Name` had type `string`, then because there is an implicit conversion from one (`string`) to the other (`object`), it would work fine with `.ConvertSomething(data, x => x.Id, x => x.Name)`. In the actual case, you could "fix" your problem by saying `.ConvertSomething(data, x => (object)x.Id, x => x.Name)` (note cast to `object`).

Comment: Yes of course, but I explicitly wanted two property expressions and can happily add another type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the type of `Id` and `Name` are different. since object is compatible with both of them you are able to call it specifying object. You can add a third generic argument like this:

```
IList<T> ConvertSomething<T, TValue, TName>(
     IList<T> original, 
     Expression<Func<T, TValue>> valuePropertyExpression, 
     Expression<Func<T, TName>> namePropertyExpression);
```

Then the types should be inferred correctly.

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much. Will accept when I can.